# Expected value/variance with respect to two randomly selected 2-digit numbers

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have two two-digit numbers. Each digit (4 in total) is chosen independently and can be either 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6.

For example, the two numbers can be 35 and 22.

What's the expected value of the product of these two numbers? What about the variance of their sums?

I first found the number of possible combinations: there are 5 random digits to choose from, so $5! \cdot 2$ to account for the two numbers. What do I do from here?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4$ be the four digits, so your numbers are $Y_1 = 10 X_1 + X_2$ and $Y_2 = 10 X_3 + X_4$.  The product is $$Y_1 Y_2 = 100 X_1 X_3 + 10 X_1 X_4 + 10 X_2 X_3 + X_2 X_4$$  Then $$ \eqalign{\mathbb E[Y_1 Y_2] &= 100\; \mathbb E[X_1 X_3] + 10 \;\mathbb E[X_1 X_4] + 10\; \mathbb E[X_2 X_3] + \mathbb E[X_2 X_4]\cr 
&= 100\; \mathbb E[X_1] \mathbb E[ X_3] + 10\; \mathbb E[X_1] \mathbb E[X_4] + 10 \;\mathbb E[X_2]\mathbb E[ X_3] + \mathbb E[X_2 ] \mathbb E[X_4]}$$
using the linearity of expected value and the fact that independent random variables are uncorrelated.

Similarly, use the formulas for variance of a sum of independent random variables and a multiple of a random variable.

Comment: So to find E[X1] i can just take the average of 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, which is 4. And E[X1] = E[X2] = E[X3] = E[X4] so for the equation you give I can just plug in 4 to get the expected value of the product of these two numbers?